# Does the Read-Only configuration of a DC apply only to Active Directory?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory, read-only

Firstly, I'm not sure how friendly the users of this site are to students but my question seems to be well suited.

I am configuring a domain with multiple Windows Server 2008 machines and am curious whether I can successfully install certain roles on a read-only domain controller.  I'm not sure whether the read-only configuration applies only to the Active Directory role or to other roles on that server.  I ask because I am unable to make changes to DNS from the read-only machine, which leads me to believe that other roles would also be affected in this way.  I do know that the issue with DNS may be because it relies on Active Directory, but still I am unsure.

Thanks to anyone who takes the time to read and answer my question.

Comment: Welcome to SF!  We don't bite - usually :)  This is a good question.  Best thing to keep in mind is to pay attention to the FAQ and to work as hard with your situation as we do helping you with it.  Students are welcome!  But the homework questions where you want all the answers are not.  Keep that in mind and you're usually good.

Comment: You get a +1 from me just for being up front and not asking us to pass exams for you, like so many others have done. Good question as well.

Answer (score 6):

Check this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732801(WS.10).aspx

Here is the meat from that article (notice the last item, it relates to your DNS issues):

---

What new functionality does this feature provide?

RODC addresses some of the problems that are commonly found in branch offices. These locations might not have a domain controller. Or, they might have a writable domain controller but not the physical security, network bandwidth, or local expertise to support it. The following RODC functionality mitigates these problems:

Read-only AD DS database

Unidirectional replication

Credential caching

Administrator role separation

Read-only Domain Name System (DNS)

---

Comment: sure thing, keep an eye on your post here, as other sys admins might chime as well with their worth while input =)